# ASP.NET 5 Template web application external authenication

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, facebook-authentication

I am sure there is something small I am missing in this process but all the videos I have watched seem to have a different setup than I have and it is causing problems with my application. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and my setup process was as follows;

File new project
Using .net framework 4.6 ASP.NET 5 Web Application, Individual Authorization

Created that project, then opened the startup.cs file and it tells me to go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715 for adding external authentication

This web site tells me to create the facebook app, which I have completed. However, the next step titled "Use SecretManager to store Facebook AppId and AppSecret" I get lost. I did the first step in the install the Secret Manager, but after that I am lost again. Can anyone help me in getting the external authorization.

Also something worth noting, in all the videos I have watched their solution explorer doesn't look the same as mine.

Mine looks like this
[Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3R6p.png)

where in videos the solution explorer looks more like a normal tree

Thank you for any answer possible, as well thank you for any time spent in creating a small guide if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your Facebook *AppId* and *AppSecret* in appsettings.json 
Add this string in appsettings.json file. Relpace XXXX with your *AppId* and *AppSecret* numbers.

```
"Authentication": {
    "Facebook": {
      "AppId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "AppSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Use it in Startup.cs in method public void Configure(....) {..} like this:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
{
   AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
   AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"]
});
```